# Loading coredata for two collection views and one table view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, uicollectionview

So I have this issue where I have to load one entity on two collection views, and one table view. The thing is, primarily I just had to load one entity on the VC where the tableview is located. And that data entity has these parameters for i.e.:

- Engine type (diesel or petrol)
- Car color
- Max.velocity
- Year of production

Now, the main point was, to color the cells on the tableview depending on the type of the car engine. So, if the data Entity "Car" has a Bool value of "isEngineDiesel" = true, then the cell would be orange, if false, then it would be light blue. And this worked just fine, a simple if statement on the table view delegate method for loading such cells. But, now I had to implement another VC which has two collection views, in which, the first one loads ONLY Diesel engine Car entity's, and the other Petrol  type. 
So I guess the issue is already clear here. How can I accomplish this? Because after countless hours of experimenting the only idea I had was two make TWO entity's in which the one is DieselCar and the other PetrolCar. But that means changing the complete data structure, and also, instead of one table view I would actually need two, which doesn't seem like a good idea due the fact that it would "overflow" with all the data there is.

So...any ideas gents?

EDIT:

So far I've only managed to get the cell titles, but the return value of number of cells is still a mystery on how to solve.
The Code for collection view delegate:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    if let carData = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Car {

    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true


        if collectionView == collectionViewDiesel {
            if carData.isEngineDiesel == true {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: 0x8DF060)
                // Display the cell name

                cell.cellTitle.text = carData.cellTitle
            }
        }else if collectionView == collectionViewPetrol {
            if carData.isCarDiesel == false {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: 0xEB9B2D)
                // Display the cell name

                cell.cellTitle.text = carData.cellTitle
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

And this is the method I need answered:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the other VC you need data structure for two collection views so I think make a dictionary from your data base on the isEngineDiesel if true add objects in one array and if false in another array then set those arrays for the respective diesel and petrol keys .
In you collection view delegate there always a UICollectionView argument place check on that (you can use tags or even == operator if you have outlet)  to load the data from dictionary base on keys .

Comment: Um, yeah, I thought of that but since it's a large entity, a sample code would be greatly appreciated. Plus for the record in case someone else runs into this issue.

Comment: If it's a large entity you can directly load the data in respective arrays using the predicate

Comment: I can post the sample for the collection view delegate function with sample data but not with whole scenario

Comment: Sample will do just fine, I have everything else :)